# How to query the column names of a Spark Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `val ds: Dataset[Double]` (in Spark 2.0.0), but what is the name of the double-valued column that can be passed to `apply` or `col` to convert from this 1-columned `Dataset` to a `Column`.

Answer (score 12):

The column name is "value" as in `ds.col("value")`.  `Dataset.schema` contains this information: `ds.schema.fields.foreach(x => println(x))`

Answer (score 10):

You could also use `DataFrame`'s method `columns`, which returns all columns as an Array of Strings.

```scala
case class Person(age: Int, height: Int, weight: Int){
  def sum = age + height + weight
}

val df = sc.parallelize(List(Person(1,2,3), Person(4,5,6))).toDF("age", "height", "weight")

df.columns
//res0: Array[String] = Array(age, height, weight)
```